# Schedule to trigger a call to backend at specific time

Tags: ios, swift

I currently have a feature that takes a dict `[MyEndPoint:[Date]]` of endpoints and dates and then triggers a call to each endpoint immediately, ignoring the dates. This must run as a response to a silent notification (ie, it must complete in 30 seconds and is a background thread).

I'd like to change my current functionality to trigger these calls only during the dates in the Array value ... how do I do that?

Comment: Have you tried setting up a dispatch after 30 seconds with a {continue} if the time is not in the array?

Comment: interesting -- I thought that all your threads that you spun up in response to a silent notification had to complete in 30 seconds ("Your app has 30 seconds of wall-clock time to perform any tasks and call the provided completion handler."). You're saying that I can just spin up new queues at specific times?

Comment: I actually do not know that @roberto. I have not tried to do the call on a silent notification, and I misread your problem. I thought your stuck point was the comparison to the array of dates.